# Voice Over Mac OSX ignores lang attribute

Tags: accessibility, voiceover, screen-readers

I'm stuck with a problem I can't put my finger on. I have a simple link English link on a Dutch page.

```
<html lang="nl">
…
<a href="link" lang="en">Read more about bunnies</a>
…
</html>
```

When I test this with my Voice Over screen reader on mac the link is still read out by the Dutch voice and with a Dutch pronunciation? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

With VoiceOver on the iPhone (I know you're asking about the Mac), I don't have to load any voice packs in order to switch languages.  However, on a PC using NVDA, NVDA will not switch voices if I don't have the language installed.

```html
<a href="link" lang="en">Read more about bunnies</a>
<a href="link" lang="fr">En savoir plus sur les lapins</a>
<a href="link" lang="es">Leer más sobre conejitos</a>
<a href="link" lang="it">Leggi di più sui conigli</a>
<a href="link" lang="nl">Lees meer over konijntjes</a>
```

*(I have no idea if the above translations are correct. I just used google translate.)*

All 5 examples above switch voices when I test on the iPhone even though I only have English, Spanish and French installed in my VoiceOver rotor (Settings > Accessibility > VoiceOver > Speech > Rotor Languages).  But on the PC, only the English, Spanish, and French examples read properly.  The others read as if it's English (my default language setting).

I'm not sure about VoiceOver on the Mac. Perhaps you have to install the language in order to hear it? However, I'm guessing you probably have both English and Dutch already installed on your Mac so that might not be the problem.

Are you able to test your example on an iPhone?

Can you also try different versions of English with the country code specified in the `lang` and see if any will announce properly?

- "en-US" (USA)
- "en-GB" (Great Britain)
- "en-AU" (Australia)
- "en-NZ" (New Zealand)
- "en-CA" (Canada)
- "en-IE" (Ireland)
- "en-ZW" (Zimbabwe)

Comment: Hi, I got all languages installed. Thing is that the autodetection seems to overwrite the lang attribute. When the text is short, one or two words or starts with a dutch word it switches to Dutch even when I add a lang attribute. So the button 'Read more' is read in Dutch I think because it's to short. And sentences starting with a Dutch city name are in Dutch because the first word in a Dutch word. Any idea if I can manage the autodetection settings somewhere?

Comment: I don’t have a Mac so am not sure about those settings. Can you test on an iphone to see if it switches? That might rule out a code problem. Do you have a PC emulator on your Mac so you can try a PC screen reader? That would also help rule out a coding problem.